# How to tab between buttons on an Mac OS X dialog box

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, dialog

I know that there has been a similar question asked here very recently, but I was wondering if it was possible to tab between buttons on default Mac OS X dialog boxes?

I already have the *All controls* option enabled in *System Preferences* → *Keyboard & Mouse* → *Keyboard Shortcuts*, but no joy.

Comment: It's not the answer to the question but I feel it's relevant. You can tab backwards through the controls and boxes using shift+tab.

Comment: See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254136/tab-key-not-working-properly-in-dialogue-boxes-in-macos

Answer (score 203, accepted):

If you enable Full Keyboard Access by setting it to all controls, you should be able to tab between options and select by hitting spacebar, at least for OS X 10.5:

[image: Full Keyboard Access: All Controls (Control+F7)]

Comment: Thanks. At least in Lion, this setting can also be switched on or off quickly using Ctrl+F7.

Comment: Not much use though is it, since the OS doesn't always focus the dialog... :/

Comment: El Capitan, not working anymore.

Comment: The Keyboard shortcut still works on El Capitan Fn+Ctr+F7 toggles it on/off.

Comment: Thanks - took me a while to find out even when I already knew that months ago - wonder why spacebar - why not just enter key - its not intuitive and you could always switch back to the highlighted button in 1-2 strokes if you make an error. Sometimes I feel like there is some evil manager behind the guys who do this in Apple and hes pushing his stupid ideas into releases. And yep confirming it still works on El Captain for me too.

Comment: I am somehow new to mac, I now can toggle between different bottoms but how can I press on don't save with the keyboard. I press return (or enter) but it was just saving. Can you help, please?

Comment: Switching focus works now but cannot select

Comment: In Monterey 12.3.1 it is `use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls` in Sys.pref. -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts on window bottom. Toggle with `Ctrl+f7`.

Comment: Nice! this is very helpful

Comment: In Monterey as my macbook, can tab thru controls BUT NOT thru textbox

Answer (score 89):

While [@ruddzw's (chosen) answer](https://superuser.com/a/473145/53740) works, it can slow you down in other areas simply from the sheer number of controls there are to tab through.

[@NReilingh presents a different approach](https://superuser.com/a/176003/53740), and the semantics behind it:

> The right way to go about keyboard shortcuts for alternate dialog buttons is not tab, but *command key combos*. For example, *Command-period* is almost universally "cancel." [...]
>   It's often not documented, but the command shortcut for different buttons that aren't the default button or cancel is usually *the first letter of that button*.

So in the example:

[image: Save prompt]

- <kbd>enter</kbd>/<kbd>return</kbd> will *Save*,
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>esc</kbd> will *Cancel*, and
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will map to *Don't Save*.
  As [@Kevin Reid points out](https://superuser.com/questions/473143/#comment666754_547501), <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> works here as well.

Comment: In the new combined save/do-you-want-to-save dialog boxes, "Don't Save"'s shortcut is ⌘-Delete.

Comment: Both `⌘+D` and `⌘+delete` seem to map to _Don't Save_.

Comment: didn't work for me (brand new osx with latest os whatever it is), so enabled all controls, but thanks, I'd have preferred your answer if it had worked. I did test all the keys on the keyboard, with FN, CTRL, Option as well.

Comment: You can also press "Tab" key to select focus on button and then press "Space" instead of "Enter" to apply the selection.

Comment: This is good info beyond the accepted answer, still in the scope of the question asked.

Comment: Works for mac OS Mojave

Answer (score 16):

In *Keyboard preferences* under `Keyboard Shortcuts`

Full Keyboard Access:
`Switch to All Controls` instead of `Text Boxes and Lists Only`

Answer (score 7):

To enable navigation using Tabs from the command line type:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleKeyboardUIMode -int 3
```

Comment: What is the difference between int 2 and 3?
In macOS Monterey, 2 is sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

In Ventura (MacOS 13) this has moved again, to a
[Keyboard navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20uPK.png) toggle in `System Settings > Keyboard`.

Comment: Same for Sonoma (macOS 14).

Answer (score 7):

1. Visit **System Settings**
2. Find or search for **Keyboard**
3. Under **Keyboard Navigation** ensure the switch is on

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know about macOS Ventura.

Answer (score 6):

In macOS Monterey (12.4) this option changed a little bit and looks like this:
[image: macOS Monterey Keyboard Shortcuts]

I had the option "Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls"  enabled but I wasn't able to tab between OK and Cancel in the Finder's delete dialog. I had to disable and reenable that option, so it was working again as expected.

Comment: And also not having the options for All kind of controls e.g. textbox. In Monterey as my macbook, can tab thru controls BUT NOT thru textbox

Answer (score 3):

Is there a specific dialog you're having trouble with? With "All controls" enabled I can tab around every control of every Mac OS X dialog I've tested just now.

Answer (score 2):

In macOS Catalina, do the following.

In Settings Preferences, navigate to `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts`. Select `Keyboard` in the left pane. Tick the `Use Keyboard navigation` and untick `Change the way Tab moves focus` options.

Here's the image for reference: 
[Keyboard Shortcuts preferences window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjzEM.png)

Comment: In your screenshot at the bottom there's a checkbox for `Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls`.  I think *that's* the one that changes the tab behaviour.  The one you've given disables the `Ctrl-F7` shortcut, which actually allows you to toggle that without going into Settings.

Comment: @mwfearnley yes what you said worked for me. Not the other setting mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

**NEW SOLUTION:**

`System Settings` --> `Keyboard` --> `Keyboard Navigation`

[image]

**PREVIOUS SOLUTION:**

The only way that I was able to make it work on `macOS Sonoma 14.4` was like this:

1. `Create` a `Untitled.txt` file.
2. `Rename` that file to `Untitled.md` in Finder.
3. `A dialog will pop-up` asking you to confirm that you want to change the file extension (look at the provided screenshot).
4. When you have the dialog open `click`: `control`+`f7` (or `control`+`fn`+`f7`)
5. Now you can more to the next button with the `tab` key on your keyboard and click `space` to confirm/click on the button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When browsing with Safari, you can also tab between all HTML elements on the page using Option+Tab (otherwise Tab would only stop on the browser toolbar controls and quick bookmarks)