# Are there shortcut keys in Mac to navigate to a button?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

Usually the dialog has 3 buttons - Cancel, No and Okay. In Windows, I can do Alt+O to select Okay. How to do this in Mac?

Comment: Related: [How to tab between buttons on an Mac OS X dialog box](http://superuser.com/questions/473143/how-to-tab-between-buttons-on-an-mac-os-x-dialog-box).

Comment: @Arjan Thanks! I'm looking for key combinations which should be more efficient for me than tab, tab, tab, enter:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape selects cancel buttons and return (↩) selects OK buttons. ⌘⌫ or ⌘D often selects buttons like Don't Save. Enter (⌅ or fn-return) selects a default button when the focus is on a multi-line text field (like in some crash report dialogs).

If you enable full keyboard access from the keyboard preference pane, you can focus buttons by pressing tab.

[image]