# How can I find an alias to a server that no longer exists on Mac M1Max Verntura 13.2

Tags: find, alias

I installed Carbonite on my Mac. Every time it runs it produces an Apple dialogue box that says it is unable to find the server "Craig's Computer Server". Note the ' mark.   This causes Carbonite to freeze. After hours working with Carbonite and searching on my own, I have not been able to find the file or alias causing this problem. I suspect an alias pointing to this server, that has not existed for a couple of decades. It had been my son's computer before he left home. Spotlight does not find it.

I have tried numerous commands in Terminal such as

```bash
sudo find / -name Craig*/*.* -print  
sudo find / -name "Craig's Computer Server"/*.* -print
```

Comment: See these [post1](https://superuser.com/questions/902869/how-to-identify-which-process-is-running-which-window-in-mac-os-x) and [post2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391607/how-to-find-the-application-that-controls-system-dialog-window) for methods for identifying dialogs.

Comment: There has been no answer to this question. Is there a way to list all aliases on a Mac?  How is a server name referred to in the path to a file? Can I search for files directed to particular server? Thanks.

Comment: I did post above a comment. Try to see if any of the links helps, or if they add more information about the problem then [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1771008/edit) it into your post.

Comment: Simply using spotlight I was able to search for all aliases and servers, and although it is inconvenient I moved them all to an external hard drive and deleted them. This might fix the problem - so far so good!

Comment: harrymc
Thank you for those two useful posts. Fascinating. I am a PHP programmer, not familiar with Python so I liked the simple AppleScript option which I will try next time this problem appears. 
Sorry I missed your post. Quite difficult to spot with one line of small text and the counter on the left still said '0' which may be a bit misleading(?). Of course I am new to this forum. Thank you again for your help.