# How to enable the Tab key for navigating OS X Yosemite dialog boxes and buttons

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I enable the Tab key for navigating OS X Yosemite dialog boxes and buttons?  When I hit tab it should jump between save, do not save, cancel items.

Is there keyboard shortcut in Yosemite for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tab between buttons on an Mac OS X dialog box](http://superuser.com/questions/473143/how-to-tab-between-buttons-on-an-mac-os-x-dialog-box)

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Control-F7</kbd> (you may need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> too).

Or go to *System Preferences » Keyboard » Shortcuts* and tick *All Controls* at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to tab.

Save is  <kbd>Enter ⌅</kbd>  or  <kbd>Return⏎</kbd>

Don't Save is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Cancel is  <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, Don’t save = command + Esc  doesn’t work for me still

Comment: It should probably be Command-Delete (i.e. Command-Backspace).

Comment: ach - right, sorry, fixed. [I'm still used to Cmd/D from before Lion…]