# OS wide Vimium/Vimperator for dialog box (osx)

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, dialog

I know there is a way [*] to tab between buttons in osx' dialog boxes.

Is there a way to select buttons with keyboard's letters just like Vimium (the google Chrome plugin) does ?

Because hitting tab sometimes 10 times is not very efficient...

[*] see for instance: [How to tab between buttons on an Mac OS X dialog box](https://superuser.com/questions/473143/how-to-tab-between-buttons-on-an-mac-os-x-dialog-box)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [Shortcat](http://shortcatapp.com/)—you'll need to type more than with Vimium but otherwise it does pretty much what you want. Even if you won't be able to jump directly to some element, you can jump to a nearby one and hit tab a few times.

Comment: This is great !

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in https://vimacapp.com/. The flow is quite similar to Vimium. I'm actively developing it.